# I can't get the ID variable using mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to execute this sql query but it doesn't insert in the correct ID. I'm trying getting the last ID using mysqli_insert_id but without result. Thanks for the help!

```
$sql = "insert into desechados 
                (rutrep, rutempr, nombreusu, apematusu, 
                apepatusu, nombempr, giroempr, direempr, 
                corrusua, numeusua) 
        select rutrepr, rutempr, nombusua, apematus, 
                apepatus, nombempr, giroempr, direempr, 
                corrusua, numeusua 
        from usuario 
        where rutrepr='".$_SESSION['rutrep']."'";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
}

$razonrechazo = $_POST['oculto'];   

$sql1 = "insert into desechados (razonrechazo) values ('$razonrechazo') where (iddesechados=".$last_id.") ";
mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
```

Comment: What happens when you Echo `$last_id`??

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), your program is vulnerable.

Comment: You should put the last 3 lines inside of your if statement. That way, if the query fails, it won't attempt to insert an empty ID. You should also add an else statement to check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: @RotimiOlawale I get the correct value, so the problem must be in the last query

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: `$razonrechazo = $_POST['oculto']; ... $sql1 = "insert into desechados (razonrechazo) values ('$razonrechazo') ... "; ... mysqli_query($con, $sql1);`.

Comment: @stickybit Woops how come I did not see that, you are right

Comment: @LuisEscobar: `WHERE` clauses are invalid in `INSERT` statements (without a `SELECT`, hence `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)`). Try to remove it from your second one. Maybe it just didn't run at all because of that.

Comment: @pegajosa it worked! I didn't notice, sorry I'm new in programming. Instead an insert I changed it by update and it worked. Thank you